# backface-visibility doesn't work and perspective() issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a card flipping animation that have front text and back text. But, I'm stuck at making the back text appear.

This is the CSS:

```
body{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.card{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 2s ease;
}

.card:hover{
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.back{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <span class='front'>Front</span>
    <span class='back'>End</span>
</div>
```

There's also an issue about the perspective: If I try to hover for the first time it doesn't work then it work and sometime the perspective is too much like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotating the children elements instead of the container would help achieve the effect you want.

Here is what we do in the below snippet:

- A container element which is transparent and has a `perspective` property assigned to it. Setting this on the parent automatically applies it to both children elements.
- Two absolutely positioned block children elements who have 100% width and height of the parent container element. Both these elements have `background` as red. Their `backface-visibility` is hidden which means that when the elements are rotated by +/- 180deg the backside is not shown (and thus the mirror appearance of text does not show up).
- Initially the front element is not rotated and the back element is rotated by 180deg. This keeps the front element on top and sends the back element behind. Because of `backface-visibility`, the content of the element behind is hidden.
- On hovering the container, the front element is rotated by -180deg and so it goes behind whereas the back element is brought to the front.

Regarding the other issue, I am not able to simulate it but I am confident that using this method should solve that issue also.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  perspective: 2000px; /* applies to both children */
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); /* originally this is behind */
}
.card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg); /* on hover it is brought to front */
}
.card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* on hover front is sent back */
}
.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class='front'>Front</span>
  <span class='back'>End</span>
</div>
```

Comment: oh yeah sorry anyway for the late reply .. i was busy

Comment: @AltianoGerung It's ok pal. No worries :)

Comment: can i ask you something. could test my css again but this time add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` in `.card` rule

Comment: @AltianoGerung: Yes that is one solution but [IE does not support that property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) till IE11 and that's why I had not recommended it :)